# Exception_Stack_Overflow error in Command Line Script

Tags: command-line

I'm new user of Blender. I decided to give it a go in order to create a simple animation for a Youtube channel. I found a template, made the changes I wanted, and then saved it, but there's a problem when I go to render it. From the in-program window, I go to render it, and then the program immediately crashes. To work around this, I studied up on how to do it from the command line, and I was able to get it to work once, but the text came out all screwed up, so I needed to re-do it. Now, every time I go to render it from the command line, I get "EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW", and it fails. I have attached an image of the exact command line script after attempting to render the animation.

Computer Specs:
Dell Precision M4500 | Windows 7 Professional 64-Bit | Intel Core i7 | Q740 @ 1.73 GHz | 10.0 GB Ram
[image: Blender Command Line Error]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Many will suggest rendering to an image sequence, then convert the image sequence to a video file when done (images to video is a quick operation). Your first error is that `-F AVI` is invalid, this could be leading to repeated errors that cause the overflow. Valid video options include AVIRAW and AVIJPEG see [the manual for option info](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line.html#format-options)

Comment: Thanks, however I fixed the AVI error, and also tried rendering it out to an image sequence (PNG), and that also resulted in an EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. As it turns out, the font I was using was overloading it. I erased all of the text, created a test file, and it rendered out just fine. Guess I will need to either find a different version of the same font, or find an entirely different font to use.